# Python dataclass to dictionary of lists

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

From a list of dataclasses (or a dataclass B containing a list):

```
import dataclasses
from typing import List

@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    b: int
  
@dataclasses.dataclass
class B:
  l: List[A]
  
da = B([A("a", 3), A("b", 4)])
# or
da = [A("a", 3), A("b", 4)]
```

I'd like to get to a dictionary of lists:

```
# {'a': ['a', 'b'], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

The only way I found was with an ugly loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
for item in da:
  for field in dataclasses.fields(item):
    res[field.name].append(getattr(item, field.name))
print(res) # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['a', 'b'], 'b': [3, 4]})
```

Seems like such a simple thing to do that there must be an easier way and more pythonic.

Comment: I don't see a common enough reason to do this to justify a different syntax. Transposed data structures like that is generally considered bad practice since it's really easy to get them out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *ugly loop* is actually not that bad. If you want to make it a one-liner, use `functools.reduce`:

```py
import dataclasses
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce
from typing import Any, List, Protocol, Sequence, cast


@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    a: str
    b: int


@dataclasses.dataclass
class B:
    l: List[A]


class Dataclass(Protocol):
    __dataclass_fields__: dict[str, Any]


def to_dict_of_lists(_dataclasses: Sequence[Dataclass]) -> dict[str, list[Any]]:
    return reduce(
        lambda acc, x: {field.name: acc[field.name] + [getattr(x, field.name)] for field in dataclasses.fields(x)},
        _dataclasses,
        cast(dict[str, list[Any]], defaultdict(list)),
    )


da = [A("a", 3), A("b", 4)]

print(to_dict_of_lists(da))  # {'a': ['a', 'b'], 'b': [3, 4]}
```

Diclaimer: this is inefficient and less readable that the simple loop. Treat it rather as a fun fact.

Answer (score 0):

It's a few other ways to do this but all of them will be about iterating through the list of values. Your solution for this result is pretty fine.

`dataclasses.asdict` might help you but you can't avoid iteration through the list.